# ¿Es normal que Xampp se instale mal en ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xampp

Estoy instalando Xampp a petición de un superior en el trabajo, descargue la versión más nueva y use los comandos:

```
chmod 775 xampp-linux-64-7.4.1-1-installer.run
```

```
sudo ./xampp-linux-64-7.4.1-1-installer.run
```

En un principio todo bien nada mal, la instalación toma su tiempo pero normal en una maquina virtual en un pc un poco sobrecargado, llega el momento de la verdad y...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No solo el símbolo sale mal, sino que también MySQL Database se niega a correr (también tengo problemas con apache web server pero eso lo soluciono con una linea de comando).

También al cerrar la ventana, Xampp literalmente no está, ni en el buscador de ubuntu, ni con locate, ni nada.

Y cuando voy a Go To Application, se congela intentando iniciar los servidores.

Ya he intentado instalar, desinstalar y reinstalar unas 3 veces, también probé reiniciando la máquina virtual.

No se si esto sirva, pero la version de Xampp es 7.4.1-1, la versión de Ubuntu es 18.04

Comment: Aprovechando que es Ubuntu, no te animas a instalar MySql, Apache+PHP común y corriente? Pues, sin el manager que es XAMPP.

Comment: ¿Sabes que es irónico? tengo todo ya hecho (de hecho es para una app en laravel, ya tengo laravel corriendo). 

De todas formas me pidieron que use Xampp para aquello

Comment: Qué errores te lanzan los logs de Apache y MySql. Como sugiere @Alfabravo es lo ideal en entornos de producción, de hecho instalar MySql, Apache y PHP en Windows también es fácil, pero nos malacostumbramos a los paquetes cuando estamos estudiando y luego nos liamos con errores simples.

Comment: Significa que POSIBLEMENTE tengas conflictos entre lo ya instalado y lo de XAMPP porque usan los mismos puertos (y seguro arrancas todo al iniciar, así que lo de XAMPP va a montar socket por 3306 o por el 80 y encuentra los puertos ocupados). Las cosas que pasan por traer cosas de Windows al maravilloso mundo de Linux :D

Comment: Eso es otra ironia, tenía todo corriendo en windows (sin xampp) y aun así me pidieron cambiarlo a linux 

Desisntalaré Xampp y veré si puedo hacer las cosas por separado. Lo que dijiste de usar los puertos me da mucho pero que muuucho sentido

Comment: Hola @hugo antes de reinstalar prueba a asignar otros puertos p.ej 89 y 3316 usa números que sean poco probables para haber sido usados por otra instalación. En la pestaña **manage servers** señalas el servidor y a derecha aparece una opción de configuración

Comment: Ya que estás con ubuntu y laravel, sería más interesante que trabajaras con docker, creando el dockerfile/docker-compose necesario para instalar MySQL, PHP, apache/nginx... Hay muchos ejemplos, y es lo que se está usando en sistemas de despliegue, más que instalar servidores tipo lamp y demás...

Answer (score -1):

Para Linux no se usa XAMPP, se usa **LAMP** (Linux, Apache, Mysql, PHP)

Tienes más info de como instalarlo en:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-instalar-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-en-ubuntu-16-04-es

Comment: Hasta donde yo sé, XAMPP es multiplataforma: afirmar categóricamente que en Linux no se usa XAMPP no parece del todo correcto.